# getElementsByClassName, recursion, one parameter, no underscore.js

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to write `getElementsByClassName()` without using the `getElementsByClassName` method or the _. methods. I want to use recursion with the function having only one parameter, then push each value into an array. Afterword return that array. Below is my code so far. I have tried several versions, what am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

I realize that this question has been asked before and answered. However, I am trying to write the function using only one parameter, others use two. I am also using no _. underscore methods, others use underscore. I need to use recursion using no underscore, only one parameter, and can not use the `getElementsByClassName` method. I have been working on this for quite awhile and would love some help thanks!

```
var getElementsByClassName = function(className) {
  var nodeArray = [];
  var fakeNode = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

  // var variableNode = document.getElementsByClassName(className); // ['element 1', 'element 2', 'element 3']

  if(document.nodeName === className) {
  var variableNode = document.querySelector(className);

  // base case: 
    if (variableNode.length === 0) {
        return [];

  // rec case:
    } else {
        for(var i = 0; i < variableNode.length; i++) {
            nodeArray.push(variableNode[i]);
        }
        getElementsByClassName();
    }
  }
  return nodeArray;
};
```

Comment: why do want to re-invent the wheel?. Have a look on the polyfill version https://gist.github.com/eikes/2299607

Comment: If you want to notify someone that you've commented, you have to put @ before their name.

Comment: @Li357 the above response is not related to the DOM either which is why I asked the question. I reformatted the actual question for you. But, in the title I put uses no underscore, only one parameter, and uses recursion for clarification. Could you please reopen the question? Thank you

Comment: The number of parameters is irrelevant. When you recurse, you have to return the value of the recursive call, e.g. `return getElementsByClassName(...);`. But you also need to use different parameters each time -- the recursive call has to get you closer to the base case.

Comment: Why do you think you need recursion here?

Comment: So this *is* a duplicate, just with an additional problem?

Comment: Yes, it seems to have lots of problems, not just the problem in the dupe.

Comment: @Barmar I understand that. It is just that I am only allowed to use one parameter and no underscore methods either. I put // base in the code to make it easier for where I am setting the base though.

Comment: `if(document.nodeName === className)` will never succeed.

Comment: `document.querySelector(className)` will never work. A selector for a class has to begin with `.`, so it should be `document.querySelector("." + className)`

Comment: @Li357 it is a completely different solution that does not rely on _. methods and uses only the DOM and javascript from scratch using recursion.

Comment: `document.querySelector()` returns a single node or `null`, not an array. Did you mean to use `querySelectorAll()`?

Comment: @12StarlightDave The duplicate just addresses a common problem that many beginners have with recursion, which you also have. But there are so many problems in your code it's practically meaningless.

Comment: @Barmar awesome! thank you. I have been trying to figure out how I could use className because I could not do ".className" which changed the input.

Comment: @Barmar if(document.nodeName === className) does not work, what would you suggest?

Comment: @Barmar is it even possible to answer this with only one function parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do this recursively, you need to recurse through the DOM hierarchy. This means that the function has to take a DOM node to start at, then make recursive calls on all its children. At each level it creates a result array; it adds the current node if it matches the criteria, concatenates the results from the children, and then returns this result.

```js
function getElementsByClassName(className, node = document) {
  var nodeArray = [];
  if (node.classList && node.classList.contains(className)) {
    nodeArray.push(node);
  }
  if (node.children) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      nodeArray = nodeArray.concat(getElementsByClassName(className, node.children[i]));
    }
  }
  return nodeArray;
}

console.log(getElementsByClassName("a").map(e => e.id));
console.log(getElementsByClassName("b").map(e => e.id));
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="a">
  <div id="bar" class="b">
    <span id="span-1" class="a">abc</span>
    <span id="span-2" class="b">def</span>
  </div>
  <h1 id="header-1" class="a">Header</h1>
</div>
```

The base of the recursion is when you get to a node with no children, because `node.childNodes.length` will be `0` and it won't go into the loop.

Notice the default value for the `node` argument. This allows you to call the function with one argument to search the entire document, but it will use the second argument when it recurses.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer, how would I do it using only one parameter? Can I do it with only one parameter I do not see how it is possible?

Comment: I don't think so. You need a parameter that changed for every call, and you also need a parameter for the class you're looking for.

Comment: Notice that the second parameter has a default value. So you can call `getElementsByClassName("someclass")` and it will default to the `document` node. Then it will use a non-default parameter when it recurses.

Comment: okay, thank you for your explanation. It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: when I put it in sublime and run it in my spec.html doc or run it in the chrome debugger snippet it comes back as contains is undefined? What am I doing wrong. I tried doing contains("." + className) too. But, that did not work either.

Comment: Some nodes don't have a `classList`, I needed to check for that.

Comment: Why would you try changing the argument? If the function is undefined, the arguments are irrelevant.

Comment: well because it is being tested against a spec.html doc which passes arguments into the function. It is the only way I am allowed to solve for the problem. I tried to do node.classList && node.contains. But, that did not work either. If it is not of type Node how would I account for the text node?

Comment: I don't know what's different about `spec.html`, but I tested my code and it works.

Comment: Aha, I changed it to `children` so it won't process text nodes. I always forget which is which.

Comment: sweet solution! I see you changed the above. Thanks for all your help. I am learning a ton and truly appreciate your help.